# OpenOCD w/ ARM-USB-OCD-H+ARM_JTAG_SWD

Tags: jtag, swd

Has anyone been able to debug/program using SWD over a Olimex USB-JTAG programmer and the ARM-JTAG-SWD adapter? If so, please share how you did it :)

Specifically, I'm looking for what the OpenOCD configuration files would look like.

Comment: It would help if you added some details of what you are trying to program and why this setup is not working for you.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to connect to a Cortex-M3 MCU, more specifically a STM32. I'm not sure how to configure OpenOCD for SWD at all or even if its supported.

Comment: Did you RTFM? Basically, you launch openocd, passing to it some configuration parameters, then open your gdb and hook up to localhost:2222 or something. I recently went through this (hooking to a Cortex M4 core on a custom PCB) and will be happy to answer your more concrete questions.

Comment: I have been using OpenOCD flawlessly with standard JTAG connection for years, I'm just looking for a way to evaluate SWD functionality. If the FM you're referring to is this one: http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ I dont find any obvious way to switch from JTAG to SWD. Should I use the same stm32.cfg but add a "transport select swd" somewhere? Do I need to declare DAPs instead of TAPs? Maybe you can share your configuration?

Comment: I have the same question :)  Did you ever get it working?  Does anyone else have information? Thanks!

Comment: IIRC OpenOCD does not currently implement SWD. It was on the feature list but was removed. I would love to be proven wrong on that. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I cannot address the programmer, adapter, or configuration files directly.
However, to get an answer started, I did peruse the link a bit and found this:

http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Debug-Adapter-Configuration.html#Debug-Adapter-Configuration

> 8.3 Transport Configuration
>
> As noted earlier, depending on the version of OpenOCD you use, and the
>   debug adapter you are using, several transports may be available to
>   communicate with debug targets (or perhaps to program flash memory).
>
> — Command: **transport list**
>     displays the names of the transports supported by this version of OpenOCD.
>
> — Command: **transport select** transport_name
>     Select which of the supported transports to use in this OpenOCD session. The transport
>   must be supported by the debug adapter hardware and by the version of
>   OpenOCD you are using (including the adapter's driver). No arguments:
>   returns name of session's selected transport.

Presumably, selecting SWD in this manner will tell the programmer to switch to SWD and to send the JTAG->SWD transition command to the chip before programming.